# Get IP and Port from a SocketHandle

Tags: delphi, winapi, winsock

How can I get the associated `sockaddr_in` from a sockethandle so I can get the port and address from it? Or is there anything else on how to get the IP and Port from a SocketHandle?

e.g.:

```
function GetSocketPort ( s : TSocket ) : Integer;
var
  Addr                  : sockaddr_in;
begin
  // Get sockaddr_in from a socket
end;

function GetSocketAddress ( s : TSocket ) : String;
var
  Addr                  : sockaddr_in;
begin
  // Get sockaddr_in from a socket
end;

function ConnectToHost (Host : pchar; Port : Integer) : TSocket;
var
  Addr                  : sockaddr_in;
begin
  Addr.sin_family       := AF_INET;
  Addr.sin_port         := htons(Port);
  result                := Socket(AF_INET, 1, 6);
  Addr.sin_addr.S_addr  := INET_ADDR(Host);
  if not( (Connect(result, Addr, SizeOf(Addr)) = 0) ) then result := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MySocket : TSocket;
begin
  MySocket := ConnectToHost ('127.0.0.1', 8080);
  if MySocket <> 0 then begin
    // GetSocketAddress (MySocket);
    // GetSocketPort (MySocket);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`getsockname`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function for the local port and address and the [`getpeername`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738533%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the remote port  like so

```
function GetLocalSocketPort ( s : TSocket ) : Integer;
var
  Addr                  : TSockAddrIn;
  Size: integer;
begin
  Size := sizeof(Addr);
  getsockname(s, Addr, Size);
  Result := ntohs(Addr.sin_port);
end;

function GetLocalSocketAddress ( s : TSocket ) : String;
var
  Addr                  : TSockAddrIn;
  Size: integer;
begin
  Size := sizeof(Addr);
  getsockname(s, Addr, Size);
  Result := inet_ntoa(Addr.sin_addr);
end;


function GetRemoteSocketPort ( s : TSocket ) : Integer;
var
  Addr                  : TSockAddrIn;
  Size: integer;
begin
  Size := sizeof(Addr);
  getpeername(s, Addr, Size);
  Result := ntohs(Addr.sin_port);
end;

function GetRemoteSocketAddress ( s : TSocket ) : String;
var
  Addr                  : TSockAddrIn;
  Size: integer;
begin
  Size := sizeof(Addr);
  getpeername(s, Addr, Size);
  Result := inet_ntoa(Addr.sin_addr);
end;
```

Comment: `getsockname()` returns the local IP/Port that the socket is bound to. There is also `getpeername()`, which returns the remote IP/Port that the socket is connected to. Also, the reported Port is in network byte order, so you need to use `ntohs()` to convert it: `Result := ntohs(Addr.sin_port)`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I just updated the answer, I assume which the OP only wants know the local port and address, also I added the `ntohs` call.